# A Java library for formatting console output

Tags: java, console, library

In perl, there is that format facility for console output. I thought it might be good to practice some library design instead of algorithms once in a while. This may be compared to a GUI library: you start from an empty window, add some lines to it, add labels and other stuff to each line and so on. At this point I have this:

**FormatWindow.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.textui;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * This class defines a formatted text window.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Apr 13, 2016)
 */
public class FormatWindow {

    private final List<FormatWindowLine> formattedLineList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Map<String, String> fieldNameToValueMap  = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * Adds another line to this formatter.
     * 
     * @param formatWindowLine a new line descriptor.
     */
    public void addFormatWindowLine(final FormatWindowLine formatWindowLine) {
        if (formatWindowLine != null) {
            formattedLineList.add(formatWindowLine);
        }
    }

    public void setFieldValue(final String fieldName, final String value) {
        if (fieldName != null) {
            fieldNameToValueMap.put(fieldName, value);
        }
    }

    @Override 
    public String toString() {
        if (formattedLineList.isEmpty()) {
            return "";
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder()
                .append(formattedLineList.get(0).toText(fieldNameToValueMap));

        for (int i = 1; i < formattedLineList.size(); ++i) {
            sb.append("\n")
              .append(formattedLineList.get(i).toText(fieldNameToValueMap));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**FormatWindowLine.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.textui;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * This class implements a descriptor for formatted text output on a single
 * line.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Apr 13, 2016)
 */
public class FormatWindowLine {

    private final List<AbstractFormatWindowField> formatWindowFieldList = 
            new ArrayList<>();

    public FormatWindowLine addFormatWindowField(
            final AbstractFormatWindowField formatWindowField) {
        if (formatWindowField != null) {
            formatWindowFieldList.add(formatWindowField);
        }

        return this;
    }

    public FormatWindowLine addFormatWindowLine(FormatWindowLine other) {
        if (other != null) {
            other.formatWindowFieldList
                 .forEach((field) -> { addFormatWindowField(field); });
        }

        return this;
    }

    String toText(final Map<String, String> mapFieldNameToValue) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (AbstractFormatWindowField field : formatWindowFieldList) {
            sb.append(field.toText(mapFieldNameToValue.get(field.getName())));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**FormatWindowFieldAlignment.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.textui;

/**
 * This enumeration specifies all possible ways of aligning a text token within
 * a {@link net.coderodde.textui.FormatWindowField}.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Apr 13, 2016)
 */
public enum FormatWindowFieldAlignment {
    LEFT,
    CENTER,
    RIGHT,
}
```

**AbstractFormatWindowField.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.textui;

/**
 * This class defines a text field. A field is specified by its offset from the
 * start of the line, its maximum allowed length and its alignment.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Apr 13, 2016)
 */
public abstract class AbstractFormatWindowField {

    public abstract String toText(String value);

    public abstract String getName();

    protected void checkNotNegative(int number, String errorMessage) {
        if (number < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(errorMessage + ": " + number);
        }
    }

    protected void checkPositive(int number, String errorMessage) {
        if (number <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(errorMessage);
        }
    }

    protected void checkMaximumLength(int maximumLength) {
        checkNotNegative(maximumLength, "The maximum field length is negative");

        if (maximumLength == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The maximum field length is zero.");
        }
    }
}
```

**BarField.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.textui.support;

import net.coderodde.textui.AbstractFormatWindowField;

/**
 * This class implements a fixed-length character bar. A bar is a sequence of 
 * only one character.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Apr 13, 2016)
 */
public class BarField extends AbstractFormatWindowField {

    private final char barCharacter;
    private final int length;

    public BarField(final char barCharacter, final int length) {
        checkPositive(length, "The bar length must be a positive number");
        this.barCharacter = barCharacter;
        this.length = length;
    }

    @Override
    public String toText(String value) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);

        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            sb.append(barCharacter);
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**StringField.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.textui.support;

import java.util.Objects;
import net.coderodde.textui.AbstractFormatWindowField;

/**
 * This class implements a simple field consisting of a string.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Apr 13, 2016)
 */
public class StringField extends AbstractFormatWindowField {

    private final String string;

    public StringField(final String string) {
        this.string = Objects.requireNonNull(string, 
                                             "The input string is null.");
    }

    @Override
    public String toText(String value) {
        return string;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**TextField.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.textui.support;

import java.util.Objects;
import net.coderodde.textui.AbstractFormatWindowField;
import net.coderodde.textui.FormatWindowFieldAlignment;

/**
 * This class defines a simple text field.
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Apr 13, 2016)
 */
public class TextField extends AbstractFormatWindowField {

    private static final FormatWindowFieldAlignment DEFAULT_ALIGNMENT = 
                         FormatWindowFieldAlignment.CENTER;
    private static final char DEFAULT_PAD_CHARACTER = ' ';

    private final String name;
    private final char padCharacter;
    private final FormatWindowFieldAlignment alignment;
    private final int maximumLength;

    public TextField(String name,
                     char padCharacter,
                     FormatWindowFieldAlignment alignment,
                     int maximumLength) {
        this.name = Objects.requireNonNull(
                name, 
                "The name of the field may not be null.");

        checkMaximumLength(maximumLength);
        this.padCharacter = padCharacter;
        this.alignment = alignment == null ? DEFAULT_ALIGNMENT : alignment;
        this.maximumLength = maximumLength;
    }

    public TextField(String name,
                     FormatWindowFieldAlignment alignment,
                     int maximumLength) {
        this(name, DEFAULT_PAD_CHARACTER, alignment, maximumLength);
    }

    public TextField(String name, int maximumLength) {
        this(name, FormatWindowFieldAlignment.CENTER, maximumLength);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toText(String value) {
        value = value == null ? "" : value;

        if (value.length() > maximumLength) {
            return value.substring(0, maximumLength);
        }

        switch (alignment) {
            case LEFT:
                return toTextOnLeft(value);

            case CENTER:
                return toTextAtCenter(value);

            case RIGHT:
                return toTextOnRight(value);

            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown enumeration.");
        }
    }

    private String toTextOnLeft(String value) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(maximumLength);
        sb.append(value);

        while (sb.length() < maximumLength) {
            sb.append(padCharacter);
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    private String toTextAtCenter(String value) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(maximumLength);
        int leftPaddingLength  = (maximumLength - value.length()) / 2;
        int rightPaddingLength = maximumLength - leftPaddingLength 
                                               - value.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < leftPaddingLength; ++i) {
            sb.append(padCharacter);
        }

        sb.append(value);

        for (int i = 0; i < rightPaddingLength; ++i) {
            sb.append(padCharacter);
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    private String toTextOnRight(String value) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(maximumLength);
        int leftPaddingLength = maximumLength - value.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < leftPaddingLength; ++i) {
            sb.append(padCharacter);
        }

        return sb.append(value).toString();
    }
}
```

**Demo.java**:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import net.coderodde.textui.support.BarField;
import net.coderodde.textui.FormatWindow;
import net.coderodde.textui.FormatWindowFieldAlignment;
import net.coderodde.textui.FormatWindowLine;
import net.coderodde.textui.support.StringField;
import net.coderodde.textui.support.TextField;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FormatWindow window = new FormatWindow();

        FormatWindowLine[] lines = new FormatWindowLine[]{
            new FormatWindowLine(),
            new FormatWindowLine(),
            new FormatWindowLine(),
            new FormatWindowLine(),
            new FormatWindowLine(),
            new FormatWindowLine()
        };

        BarField horizontalLine = new BarField('*', 80);
        BarField innerLine      = new BarField(' ', 78);

        lines[0].addFormatWindowField(horizontalLine);
        lines[1].addFormatWindowField(new StringField("*"))
                .addFormatWindowField(innerLine)
                .addFormatWindowField(new StringField("*"));

        lines[2].addFormatWindowField(new StringField("*  First name:  "))
                .addFormatWindowField(
                        new TextField("firstName", 
                                      '_', 
                                      FormatWindowFieldAlignment.CENTER, 
                                      20))
                .addFormatWindowField(new BarField(' ', 43))
                .addFormatWindowField(new StringField("*"));



        lines[3].addFormatWindowField(new StringField("*  Last name:   "))
                .addFormatWindowField(
                        new TextField("lastName",
                                      '_',
                                      FormatWindowFieldAlignment.RIGHT,
                                      20))
                .addFormatWindowField(new BarField(' ', 43))
                .addFormatWindowField(new StringField("*"));

        lines[4].addFormatWindowLine(lines[1]);
        lines[5].addFormatWindowLine(lines[0]);

        Arrays.stream(lines).forEach(window::addFormatWindowLine);

        // Manipulating window content is easy:
        window.setFieldValue("firstName", "Ken");
        window.setFieldValue("lastName", "Thompson");

        System.out.println(window);
    }
}
```

The output is

```
********************************************************************************
*                                                                              *
*  First name:  ________Ken_________                                           *
*  Last name:   ____________Thompson                                           *
*                                                                              *
********************************************************************************
```

Any critique is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Code feedback

### No validation performed on field names

There is no validation performed on field names, if you forgot to include a field or misspell its name, it will show up as "null" on the final grid.

### Should use codepoints instead of characters

You are assuming that a character in Java represents 1 characters, [this is not true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1030066/1542723) because there are more characters than a character can hold, and they are represented by multiple characters.

Instead of getting the length of a string by using `String.length()`, use [`String.codePointCount(0, String.length())`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePointCount(int,%20int))

An extreme example of this where 1 character is more characters than 1 Java `char` is this: `n̙̹͔͎̳̰̤̆͂̾ͩ̐̏`.
Java counts that using `String.length` as 14 characters, while we see it as 1 codepoint or 1 character. Constructs similar to this are commonly used with exotic human languages, and are usually the first thing to break when translating the program to those languages.

### Don't fail silently

> ```
> public FormatWindowLine addFormatWindowField(
>         final AbstractFormatWindowField formatWindowField) {
>     if (formatWindowField != null) {
>         formatWindowFieldList.add(formatWindowField);
>     }
>
>     return this;
> }
>
> public FormatWindowLine addFormatWindowLine(FormatWindowLine other) {
>     if (other != null) {
>         other.formatWindowFieldList
>              .forEach((field) -> { addFormatWindowField(field); });
>     }
>
>     return this;
> }
>
> public void addFormatWindowLine(final FormatWindowLine formatWindowLine) {
>     if (formatWindowLine != null) {
>         formattedLineList.add(formatWindowLine);
>     }
> }
>
> public void setFieldValue(final String fieldName, final String value) {
>     if (fieldName != null) {
>         fieldNameToValueMap.put(fieldName, value);
>     }
> }
> ```

By silently failing, you are hiding the fact that there was a problem, leaving the user wondering why the code forgot to output a certain line, or forgot to set a field.

### Don't make a string is its directly going to be used in a stringbuilder again

> ```
>    for (int i = 1; i < formattedLineList.size(); ++i) {
>         sb.append("\n")
>           .append(formattedLineList.get(i).toText(fieldNameToValueMap));
>     }
> ....
> String toText(final Map<String, String> mapFieldNameToValue) {
>     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
>
>     for (AbstractFormatWindowField field : formatWindowFieldList) {
>         sb.append(field.toText(mapFieldNameToValue.get(field.getName())));
>     }
>
>     return sb.toString();
> }
> ```

You effectively making a string, just to be used once and thrown away. By making the `toText()` accept a stringbuilder instead, you prevent a useless stringbuilder and string from being made per-field, leaving less stress on the garbage collector.

---

## Design feedback

### Your output format is hardcoded

Image your business requirements change to use a 60 character output format instead of 80, you are going to need to change a lot of lines to make it look correctly.

### Should use builder pattern

By using the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), you can get a more cleaner design. An example how can you can create a GUI using a library:

```
new FormatWindowBuilder ()
    .box("*")
        .box(" ")
            .addEmptyLine()
            .startLine()
                .addLabel("First name:  ")
                .addField("firstname", 
                          '_', 
                          FormatWindowFieldAlignment.CENTER, 
                          20)
            .endLine()
            .startLine()
                .addLabel("Last name:   ")
                .addField("lastname", 
                          '_', 
                          FormatWindowFieldAlignment.RIGHT, 
                          20)
            .endLine()
            .addEmptyLine()
        .endBox()
    .endBox()
.build()
.renderAsString(80, 80);
```

---

## Code remarks

There are also things you did better than most people, and don't require changes that directly.

> ```
>     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
>
>     for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
>         sb.append(barCharacter);
>     }
>
>     return sb.toString();
> ```

Nice usage of the length argument of stringbuilder to prevent use character[] arrays from being made on the background. While this could be sped up by creating a character[] array directly and using `Arrays.fill()`, this is the most clear for everyone.